# $.support.cors clarification?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, signalr, cors

As a part of reading signalR [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) and jQuery's documentation

[jQuery's docs states](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) :

> Cors is equal to true if a browser can create an XMLHttpRequest object
>   and if that XMLHttpRequest object has a withCredentials property. To
>   **enable cross-domain** requests in environments that **do not support cors**
>   yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set
>   $.support.cors = true;

I know that *not* all browser support `CORS` (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`).

But it should be pretty simple , either it support or not.

I dont udnerstand the line :

> "To enable cross-domain requests in environments that *do not* support
>   cors yet but *do* allow cross-domain XHR requests"

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: From what I've seen this setting just tells jquery that the browser supports Cors. Other than I haven't found it useful in anyway

Comment: Some browsers support cross-origin requests but not exactly following the CORS spec. For example, IE 8 (and 9?) uses an "XDomainRequest" object for cross-origin requests, instead of XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `$.support.cors` to true you are telling jQuery and SignalR that even though jQuery's feature detection indicates that CORS is not supported, the environment executing the JS will indeed allow cross-domain XHRs.

Every time I have seen someone set this flag to true, it has been wrong. **If it set to true in an environment that really doesn't support CORS, SignalR will try to establish a cross-domain connection to the server using CORS (and fail) instead of using JSONP which would likely work**.

jQuery's feature detection (which works by looking for the withCredentials property on an XHR object) is generally accurate and *would only likely be incorrect if **not** running in a browser*. That's why the example of jQuery running in a desktop widget is given. In this case, jQuery might think that the environment doesn't support CORS because indeed it doesn't, but the environment will nonetheless allow any cross-domain request whether or not there is an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response because it's running directly on the desktop instead of in a browser.

This is how an environment could both *not* support cors, yet *allow* cross-domain XHR requests.